# deleted the Import Products Stock Profile from my Import/Export profiles

Tags: magento, import, profile

I accidentally deleted the Import Products Stock Profile from my Import/Export profiles. Can anyone give me a screen shot of this profile or confirm the settings. My store is live and I don’t have a development environment set up (i know), so any help in helping me restore this profile is much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can help yourself by Setting up a fresh Magento (same version as your site) and getting values from there.

Comment: If you have deleted just profile then you can also create new profile in admin panel system-> Import/Export -> DataFlow - Profile.